# Why am I getting VBA "Expected end of statement" for my formula code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and need some help with the following syntax.

```
Dim sumofamount As Variant
sumofamount = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Output").Range("L2:L" & lastrow))

Worksheets("Output").Range("L" & lastrow + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "" = "" & sumofamount & " ""*(1-"" R[-2]C[0] "")-"" R[-1]C[0] "
```

I'm trying to get a formula into the cell. It also has a variable that I calculated using VBA functions.

How do I combine it with regular Excel formula into the cell? I'm also using relative references because the input cells are dynamic.

Very simply, the code I want to achieve in excel is the following where L21 and L22 are the relative referenced cells.

```
=sumofamount*(1-L21)-L22
```

Comment: try `Worksheets("Output").Range("L" & lastrow + 3).Formula = "=" & sumofamount & "*(1-L21)-L22"`

Comment: Please show us full code , have you initialized lastrow variable  ?

Comment: @Maddy That doesn't make any sense because he said: *"I'm also using relative references because the input cells are **dynamic**"*. So a fixed reference to `L21`/`L22` doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not escape the quotes here, since there are no quotes in the formula. Just use individual double quotes:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & sumofamount & "*(1-R[-2]C[0])-R[-1]C[0]"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I was under the impression that to include formula from VBA, you use double quotation marks.

Comment: @GaryTang You only use double quotes in a formula that actually includes quotes. Then you need to double the quotes within the formula itself.